# Show that squares of Pearson coefficients are equal

Tags: statistics

Show that in SLR, the square of Pearson coefficient between $y$ and $ŷ, r^2_{y,ŷ}$, is equal to the square of Pearson coefficient between $x$ and $y$, $r^2_{x,y}$

I computed the least square regression line and was able to compute $r$ and $R^2$. I'm a little unclear how I'm supposed to come up with the other values? I'm probably just missing something but could use some help.

DATA:

$ X: 63, 63, 50, 60, 37, 34, 65, 47, 44, 52 $

$ Y: 49, 63, 40, 52, 44, 37, 65, 57, 38, 44 $

$ ŷ = 14.58977 + 0.66622x $

$ r =.73291 $

$R^2 = .5372 $

Comment: Please show what you have computed so far.

Comment: Edited to include progress

Comment: OK. At the moment I can only confirm your calculations, but not that $r^2_{y,ŷ}=r^2_{x,y}$

Comment: I had a typo in my formula in excel. I will give you the values I have calculated with excel.

Comment: How would you go about calculating $r^2_{y,ŷ}$?

Comment: I´ve added a picture.

Comment: I have deleted my answer. If you´re still interested in it give a reply.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the chance to see your response.

Comment: I´ve undeleted the my answer. Please give a reply if the answer is comprehensible or not.

Comment: I understood the gist of it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the picture below it can be seen how $r^2_{y, \hat y}$ can be calculated with excel-without using the RGP-function. I hope you are able to reproduce the values. If not, feel free to ask.

[image]